# Django REST Framework - Custom Permissions not Evaluating

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to set custom permissions on a class that extends viewsets.ModelViewSet and it appears that my permissions are not being evaluated.  Here is my view:

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework.authentication import SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated

import models
import serializers
from permissions import IsAdminOrAuthenticatedReadOnly

class KPIViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    '''
    API endpoint that allows KPI metadata to be viewed or edited
    '''

    authentication_classes = (BasicAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (IsAdminOrAuthenticatedReadOnly,)

    queryset = models.KPI.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.KPISerializer
```

And here is my permission class:

```
from rest_framework.permissions import BasePermission, SAFE_METHODS

class IsAdminOrAuthenticatedReadOnly(BasePermission):
    def has_permissions(self, request, view):

        if request.method in SAFE_METHODS:
            return request.user and request.user.is_authenticated()

        return request.user and request.user.is_staff()
```

The problem I'm running into is that IsAdminOrAuthenticatedReadOnly never seems to get evaluated.  I tested this both by forcing it to always return "False" and by switching the permission_classes value to "IsAuthenticated" in the view.  In the former scenario, a request to the endpoint returns as if there were no authentication requirement.  In the later, authentication is enforced as expected.

Any ideas what I'm missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method name is has_permission not has_permissions (no s) ;)